# ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT using Selenium and Cucumber in Azure

Tags: java, azure, selenium, cucumber

I am running a selenium cucumber application.
If I run my tests locally it passes my tests pass as expected.
If I run it on Azure on my release pipeline I get the following error: `org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`

Browser Version: 90.0.4430.212

ChromeDriver 90.0.4430.24

The site that I am navigating to works if I browse to it from my local browser. However I see that on azure the some tests fail with the error. If I have 15 tests about 10 will randomly fail with the error and the rest will navigate to the site fine.

My code snippet:

```
 getDriver().get(url);
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        if (driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).getText().contains("This site can’t be reached") | driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).getText().contains("ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT")) {
            driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            getDriver().get(url);
        }
```

I added the if statement after the fact because somebody suggested to clear cache.

The `url` comes from cucumber side where I gave the example.

```
    Examples:
      | url                                             |
      | https://uat.somesite.com/animal?nogeoredirect=1 |
```

The site is a UAT site but is publicaly avalible with the `?nogeoredirect=1`  added